# How does current flow in this circuit?

Tags: voltage

I am trying understand how current flows in a circuit.

In the diagram below, why don't electrons move from the negative end of battery 1, through the common wire and right light bulb, and back to the positive end of battery 1?

[image: Picture trying to illustrate the question]

Comment: Who says they don't? BTW, your image was not inserted properly.

Comment: Why does your friend control your light?

Comment: @SolarMike It's a communication system to allow you to exchange messages in morse code with a friend living in a neighbouring house without line of sight. (It's from some book I don't recall).

Comment: @Justme the book name is code:the hidden language of computer's hardware and software

Answer (score 2):

[image: circuit diagram]

Let's consider batteries as voltage sources and the bulbs as impedence loads.

If we reduce your diagram to that of a circuit diagram, we can see that there will no current in the dotted line (common wire) when all the voltages and impedances are same.

For simplicity let's assume that a bulb is a pure resistance load. In this case, if the current in the dotted line is zero and the net current is `I`, then

`V1 - I*B2 = 0` and `V2 - I*B1 = 0` and this makes trivial solution when `V1 = V2 = V` and `B1 = B2 = B`

Comment: i am actually very new in learning electricity so my question might seem stupid to you but in this circuit why don't electrons move from the negative end of v1 through the common to b2 and back to positive end of v1 as there will diffrence in their potential

Comment: Two observations that will help us is:
1. Voltage drops across a resistor as current flows through it, i.e. electrons lose energy. This loss of energy occurs in the form of heat, which is the result of collisions between the moving electrons and the atoms or ions in the resistor's material.
2. Energy is conserved in an electrical circuit. Roughly speaking, the net gain in potential energy across all voltage sources will be equal the drop in potentials across all loads in the circuit.

Comment: So yes, you are correct. The electrons can move from the negative end of V1 through common to B2 and back to positive end of V1. But this will only be case for a specific configuration of the circuit, i.e. for example, if R2 < R1 and V2 < V1.  
For some other configurations i.e. when V1 = V2 and R1 = R2, the current will not flow through the common wire. So in essence, the directions of the current change wrt the change in configuration of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It does.

Depending on the voltage of the batteries and the resistance of the light bulbs the *net current* in the black wire might be zero, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you redraw the picture to reduce the black line to a single point, you would see you have two complete circuits: {Battery 1/switch/right bulb} and {Battery 2/switch/left bulb} which touch at just a single point of contact.

With a single point of contact (and no other common such as a ground connection, or capacitive coupling) there can be no potential difference developed from one circuit in the other, so no interaction.

The two circuits would therefore operate entirely independently.